# While I am trying to read .xlsx file i am getting an error java.lang.NoSuchFieldError : SMALLER_BIG_BLOCK_SIZE_DETAILS

Tags: java, apache-poi

```
        XSSFWorkbook xSSFWorkbook = (XSSFWorkbook) WorkbookFactory.create(new File("C:\\sanjay\\InspectionFormTpl.xlsx"));
        POIFSBigBlockSize b512 = POIFSConstants.SMALLER_BIG_BLOCK_SIZE_DETAILS;

        int blockSize = 512;
        assertEquals(blockSize, b512.getBigBlockSize());

        System.out.println(" " + b512.getBigBlockSize());


        System.out.println("Workbook has " + xSSFWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets() + " Sheets : ");

        Sheet sheet = xSSFWorkbook.getSheetAt(0);
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

        Cell recordNumb = sheet.getRow(2).getCell(8);
        Cell name = sheet.getRow(5).getCell(2);
        Cell date = sheet.getRow(5).getCell(7);
        Cell time = sheet.getRow(5).getCell(10);
        Cell tagNo = sheet.getRow(7).getCell(2);
        Cell Odometer = sheet.getRow(7).getCell(6);
        Cell location = sheet.getRow(8).getCell(2);
        Cell inspector = sheet.getRow(8).getCell(5);
        Cell org = sheet.getRow(8).getCell(9);

        String recordNumber = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(date);
        String Make = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(recordNumb);
        System.out.println(" Cell =" + recordNumber + " " + name + " " + date + " " + time + " " + tagNo + " " + Odometer + " " + location + " " + inspector + " " + org);**strong text**
```

I am using Poi jars of same version 
1.poi-3.17
2.poi-ooxml-3.17
3.poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17

I am totally stuck here i found the class named 'POIFSBigBlockSize' but quite confused how to use its methods.

Comment: Check whether your classpath contains `poi-3.7.*.jar` or lower. Don't having jars of multiple different versions in class path while running.

Comment: I checked my classpath which  contains only above mentioned jars only .Can you suggest me anything else @AxelRichter

Comment: `POIFSBigBlockSize` is from the POIFS (HSSF) API ... is your file really a .xlsx? Can you open it with zip tool?